# Select command help

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables -

`table1` has 2 columns

```
Tid | times
--------------
1   | 12:00:00
2   | 15:00:00
```

`table2` also has 2 columns:

```
dates      | Tid
-------------------
2011-01-01 | 1
2011-01-01 | 2
2011-01-02 | 1
```

I want to select all times from `table1` if dates is not available in `table2` and Tid 2 from times if dates id 2011-01-02.

Comment: You might need to give more information. What do you mean by "_dates is not available_"? Are they `null`? Do you need one or two requests? Can you show an example of the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

To select all dates in T1 but not in T2:

```
select  *
from    Table1 t1
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    Table2 t2
        where   t1.tid = t2.tid
        )
```